# How to get rid of foreach loop error with readWave()?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, wav

I'm trying to run a `foreach` loop as follows:

```
foreach(i=1:n, .combine=c, .packages=c("parallel", "doParallel", "pracma", "oce", "ineq", "gsw", "seewave", "soundecology", "data.table", "openxlsx", "tuneR", "vegan")) %dopar% 
res[i,] <- indices(files[i])
```

The custom function `indices()` uses `readWave()` from the tuneR package to read wave files from a folder and loop through them. Each time I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error in readWave(x) : Object 'i' not found
```

The problem does not occur in a `for` loop. I've googled this but nobody seems to have had this one. Can anyone please help?

Comment: This is not how a `foreach` loop works. It is *not* the same as a `for` loop and you need to change how you approach it conceptually. Please study the package vignettes, e.g., [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf).

Comment: what does your custom function `indices()` do?

Comment: Maybe need `{ }`?

Comment: @awchisholm the indices function computer various sound indices for each file in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Roland for pointing me in the right direction. Yes, I was trying to use `foreach` in a conceptually wrong way, identical to how `for` loop works. I was able to get it to work by changing it so:

```
palpha <- foreach(i = 1:n, .combine = "rbind", .packages = p) %dopar% indices(files[i])
```

I was later able to write the list obtained from `foreach` to my `res` data frame so:

```
res <- as.data.frame(palpha)
```